# Adding a <span> within <li>'s from wp_nav_menu()

Tags: menus

I'm trying to format the list produced by `wp_nav_menu()` so that within each `<li>` is a `<span>` that wraps the text. At first I thought I could accomplish this using the the `items_wrap` argument, but that changes only the enclosing `<ul>`, correct? This seems like it should be simple enough to accomplish. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `items_wrap` is used to to modify or replace the default `<ul>` wrapper. To wrap the individual links inside of that element, simply use `link_before` and `link_after`, like so:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'some-location',
    'link_before' => '<span>',
    'link_after' => '</span>',
) );
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for! Is this a documented feature of `wp_nav_menu()`? I'm new to Wordpress and feel like I'm struggling to learn the basics of the functions, is there a good tutorial that covers these?

Comment: Glad it worked out, Gus! Stick with it. Yes, this is documented in the Codex under the [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) function. The WordPress source code is also documented very well, and you can usually gather a lot by searching the file system using grep/grepwin for `n whatever_function`, so in this case `n wp_nav_menu`, which will take you to the function declaration of the function you're searching for. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

One way to change the tags that wrap both the menu and its individual items is to create a custom walker. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker#General_Menu_Example